# how can i count pulses using analog pin of arduino

Tags: arduino, interrupt

The frequency of the pulses range from 1-10000 Hz and voltage ranges from 1-5 volt. I have tried the following code, its working for digital pins but not for analog.Do you guys have any solution for it.

```
 int pin = A0; 
volatile unsigned int pulse = 0;  


void setup()
```

{
Serial.begin(9600);

```
pinMode(pin, INPUT_PULLUP); 
attachInterrupt(0, count_pulse, RISING); 
} 

void loop() 
{ 
  pulse=0; 
  interrupts(); 
  delay(100); 
  noInterrupts(); 

  Serial.print("Pulses per second: "); 
  Serial.println(pulse); 
  } 

  void count_pulse() 
 { 
 pulse++; 
 }
```

Comment: How to attach interrupts and which pins support interrupts, is [clearly documented](https://www.arduino.cc/reference/en/language/functions/external-interrupts/attachinterrupt/).

Comment: It’s going to be considerably more involved on the analog side.  You aren’t going to get a simple interrupt like that.  If you know a minimum voltage level then you can use the analog comparator to get an interrupt but that is something you’ll have to set up at the register level.  There isn’t an arduino magic function to do that for you.  It will require some study of the data sheet and learning how the comparator is set up.

Comment: why do you want to use analog pins? not all pins support attachInterrupt

Comment: i was under the impression that digital pins can only read 3.3 volts as low and 5 volts as high. i am using arduino uno and didn't know that I can only use digital pins 2&3 to count interrupts, thanks to gre_gor I know now. However I have been able to count pulses using this code on pin number 2.

Comment: 3.3 V is still HIGH on 5 V ATmega

Answer (score 0):

Different Arduino boards (Mega, Uno, Nano etc) are different in terms of which pins work with interrupts. You need to read the documentation for your board, or much better, use #ifdef to adapt to any board:

```
#ifdef  __AVR_ATmega32U4__  // Leonardo has different int mapping

#ifdef __SAM3X8E__  // Due processor has different timer setup

#ifdef __AVR_ATmega328P__
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out the documentation on arduino.cc/reference.
In short if you are using the arduino uno you can only use the digital pin #2 and #3 for attachinterrupt() operation... https://youtu.be/srr0TTRPPKU

[image]